# Linux bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash

I have this code

```
echo "er453*tyu" |awk -v s=* '{print index($1,s)}'
```

The code prints 6. Now I want to reference 6 as a variable. E.g.

```
$position= "er453*tyu" |awk -v s=* '{print index($1,s)}'
```

Then use the variable position somewhere else in my code.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: @tink read through the question!
I want to reference echo "er453*tyu" |awk -v s=* '{print index($1,s)}' instead of echoing direct!

Comment: Write complete specs/example data.  As a variable WHERE? Inside the same awk script? In an encapsulating bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any command and save its stdout to a variable in Bash like this:

```
position=$(echo "er453*tyu" | awk -v s=* '{print index($1,s)}')
```

Some notes:

1. If `er453*tyu` is not supposed to expand, it would be safer to use single quotes around it. Same for `s=*`.
2. If you are running this within a function, declare `position` as a local:

```
local position
position=$(echo "er453*tyu" | awk -v s=* '{print index($1,s)}')
```

Comment: You should also have quotes around `s=*`, to keep the shell from trying to expand that.

Comment: Obvious duplicates should be closed as duplicate, not given new answers, so there's a single canonical collection of answers for each distinct question that can be as effectively vetted and edited as possible. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center.